# How to convert PHP array to JS Nested Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, php

A specific jQuery plugin used to render a **Tree-View** expects a data-string of **"Nested Array of Objects"**. My Tree-View data (in the same structure) is available in a PHP array. I need to echo the PHP array in such way that the jQuery plugin can read the data.

I already tried to **json_encode** the **PHP array** but I get a completely different result than what's expected by the jQuery plugin. The exepected/required format of the data can be viewed here:
https://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#options-data
as well as below:

```
var data = [
    {
        name: 'node1',
        children: [
            { name: 'child1' },
            { name: 'child2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'node2',
        children: [
            { name: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
];
```

My PHP array that I need to convert into the above JavaScript format (however, this is just an example):

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => CEO
            [id] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Director 1
                            [id] => 3
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Senior Manager 1
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [5] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => Manager 1
                                                            [id] => 5
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Director 2
                            [id] => 6
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [7] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Senior Manager 2
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

---

### EDIT:

This is how I generate my array:

```
$objectTempRoles = $this->roleRepository->findAll();
    $aTempRoles = [];
    foreach($objectTempRoles as $oRole){
        if($oRole->getIsroot() == 1){
            $aTempRoles[$oRole->getUid()] = [];
            $aTempRoles[$oRole->getUid()]['name'] = $oRole->getTitle();
            $aTempRoles[$oRole->getUid()]['id'] = $oRole->getUid();
            $aTempRoles[$oRole->getUid()]['children'] = $this->functionGetChildren($oRole);
        }
}


public function functionGetChildren($oRole){
    $aChildrenToReturn = [];
    if($oRole->getChildren() != null && $oRole->getChildren() != false){
        foreach($oRole->getChildren() as $oChild){
            $aChildrenToReturn[$oChild->getUid()] = [];
            $aChildrenToReturn[$oChild->getUid()]['name'] = $oChild->getTitle();
            $aChildrenToReturn[$oChild->getUid()]['id'] = $oChild->getUid();
            $aChildrenToReturn[$oChild->getUid()]['children'] = $this->functionGetChildren($oChild);
        }
    }
    return $aChildrenToReturn;
}
```

=====

## EDIT:

This is the var_dump of my array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'CEO',
    'id' => 1,
    'children' => 
    array (
      3 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Director 1',
        'id' => 3,
        'children' => 
        array (
          4 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Senior Manager 1',
            'id' => 4,
            'children' => 
            array (
              5 => 
              array (
                'name' => 'Manager 1',
                'id' => 5,
                'children' => 
                array (
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      6 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'Director 2',
        'id' => 6,
        'children' => 
        array (
          7 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'Senior Manager 2',
            'id' => 7,
            'children' => 
            array (
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

=====

## EDIT:

json_encode paramaters I've used to far: JSON_FORCE_OBJECT

=====

## EDIT:

I have now succeeded in generating the required data structure. For this, I use the following function:

```
public function getRoleChildrenJson($aParentObject){
        $json = "";
        $i = 1;
        foreach($aParentObject['children'] as $aObject){
            $tmbObjectStr = "{name: \"".$aObject['name']."\",id: ".$aObject['id'];
            if(!empty($aObject['children'])){
                $tmbObjectStr .= ",children: [";
                $tmbObjectStr .= $this->getRoleChildrenJson($aObject);
                if($i < count($aParentObject['children'])){
                    $tmbObjectStr .= "]},";
                }
            }
            else{
                $tmbObjectStr .= "}]}";
            }
            $json .= $tmbObjectStr;
            $i++;
        }
        return $json;
    }
```

However, now the strangest thing happens. While the json string is now accurate, the jQUery Plugin still doesn't accept it when I first load the string through AJAX. I.e., the following **does** work:

```
                        var data = [
                            {
                                name: 'node1', id: 1,
                                children: [
                                    { name: 'child1', id: 2 },
                                    { name: 'child2', id: 3 }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'node2', id: 4,
                                children: [
                                    { name: 'child3', id: 5 }
                                ]
                            }
                        ];
                        $('#rolestree').tree({
                            data: data
                        });
```

But, the following **doesn't** work:

```
                ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    url: "/index.php" + $getData,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "",
                    success: function (jsondata, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('#rolestree').tree({
                            data: jsondata
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Although the very same json string gets perfectly loaded over AJAX (I checked with console). Do I first need to eval or parse this data loaded over AJAX?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. We do want to help you sort out issues with your existing code, but we're not here to do all the work for you.

Comment: Please add an example PHP array we can use to test this (as opposed to its var_dump representation) and the exact `json_encode` parameters you used.

Comment: You need to build the corrrect datastructure in php and then use `json_encode()` to use it in javascript. And `array_values()` will help you convert php arrays to "real" / zero-based numeric arrays.

Comment: It would probably be useful to see hwo you create this PHP array. I am sure it could be done i a way that matches your requirement rather than trying to FUDGE this array into what is required

Comment: @ChrisG I think you are asking for a `var_export()`, _just for future reference_

Comment: I taken your php output and converted in json an this is the result: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=1a749ddc93504d2c87daee0b3887f955
So I think that is correct I don't know why is wrong could you explain why the above json is incorrect?

Comment: @DanielLuna my json is indeed correct, but the jQuery Plugin I have referenced requires a Nested Array of Objects. I have by now succeeded in creating this data structure (using a custom function), but now I run into another problem. I will update my original question/post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are returning from your PHP a json as string you have to parse it in your ajax response.

In your ajax response add the content-type

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/index.php" + $getData,
          type: "POST",                   data: "",
          success: function (jsondata, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   console.log(jsondata);
                   var json = $.parseJSON(jsondata);

                   console.log(json);
                   $('#rolestree').tree({
                        data: json
                   });
          }
      });
```

Regards